# Passing nested objects in Polymer core-ajax

Tags: ajax, json, polymer

I am trying to pass a nested object to Polymer core-ajax. Here is the code:

```
<core-ajax url="DSPUser1.php" method="POST" on-core-response="{{responseventDSPUser}}" params='{"userID":"Anon", "transactionType":"DSPUser", "payload":{"id":"1"}}' handleAs="json" id="transactionDSPUser" response="{{msgout}}">``
```

When I look at the POST in the Chrome tools I see the following under Form Data:

```
userID:Anon
transactionType:DSPUser
payload:[object Object]
```

It looks as if core-ajax is not handling nested objects.

Is this a feature or a bug?

Should I be using body instead of params?

Regardless is there a way to pass a nested object using core-ajax?

PS When I use JQuery $.POST Chrome shows the following for Form Data for a similar request

```
transactionType:DSPUSER
userdID:Anonymous
securityToken:
payload[iD]:1
```

Comment: @ted yes, I wound up passing the json object as a string using the body and then parsing the string on the other side. you can handle nested objects this way For an example see: https://github.com/Will-in-BC/aaa-jsoncrud-interface.git which also  has an example of parsing the string in php.

Comment: Yeah, I think I did the same in the end. jQuery has a nice way of "building" a json, but then I dont get it as a POST, but as a URLencoded thingie, which I dont want...

Answer (score 0):

If Im not wrong, params are converted into queryString. For POST operations you should use body instead.

Comment: When I use body the json is passed as a string instead of being parsed. I am trying to produce the same results as JQuery (see the PS in my question) as I have a common backend.

Comment: I see...It seems to be a known bug -> https://github.com/Polymer/core-ajax/issues/37